# Убрать границы в vim

Tags: vim

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать границы снизу и справа в полноэкранном режиме в vim?

Comment: не совсем ясно, о чём именно речь, но скорее всего, не о программе vim, а о программе, которая, собственно, «рисует» приведённую картинку. вы не упоминаете, что это за программа. можно предположить, что это какой-то [эмулятор терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эмулятор_терминала).

Comment: Да, извините , забыл уточнить. Это стандартный terminal mac os

Comment: 1. уточнения вопроса лучше вносить прямо в текст вопроса (нажав [edit]). 2. ну вот вы уже и определились с виновником разной толщины чёрной рамки вокруг информации, выводимой программой *vim* (если вы именно про эту чёрную рамку спрашиваете). значит, данный вопрос подлежит удалению, а задать вам надо новый вопрос. не о программе *vim*, а об эмуляторе терминала. со всем подробностями, конечно, и без не относящейся к делу информации (например, программа vim не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу).